# Why does having a large array cause NoMethodError to take longer to be raised

Tags: ruby

I have the following Ruby code where each instance of `BigClass` creates a array with instances of `BigClass` (up until a maximum depth).

```
class BigClass
  # Increase this depending on your computer performance
  MAX_DEPTH = 8

  def initialize(depth = 0)
    @my_arr = []

    5.times do |i|
      unless depth > MAX_DEPTH
        @my_arr << BigClass.new(depth+1)
      end
    end
  end
end

big_class = BigClass.new

puts "Reaches here"

# This line should throw an error but instead freezes
big_class.blah

puts "Doesn't reach here"
```

When calling a method which doesn't exist, I expect to receive a `NoMethodError` pretty much instantly, however, it seems that the larger the contents of the array in `big_class` the longer it takes for the error to be produced.

Why is this?

A few options I considered:

- Maybe Ruby does some kind of cleanup or calls some hooks for all created instances before throwing an error. But if I make the error happen from a different object or inside an existing method, it instantly raises the error.
- Maybe the Ruby method lookup for some reason includes instance variables lookup, but after reading this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/damien-roche/351bf4e7991449714533) I can't find anything to indicate that that would be the cause

Something I have noticed is that when it prints "Reached here" if I quit (CTRL-C) it will immediately print out the `NoMethodError`. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with finding whether or not the method exists, otherwise it wouldn't know that that is the error when I quit.

Comment: The method `BigClass#initialize` exists as soon as you define the class. It appears the method is called on the order of `5**(MAX_DEPTH-depth+1)` times, where `depth` is the argument of the initial call to the method. That's `5**(1) #=> 5` for `depth = 9` and `5**(10) #=>  9 765 625` for `depth = 0`. I say "on the order of" because that's just the number of calls at the lowest level.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I understand that it is being called many times, but the issue is that after all of the calls the print statement runs, and THEN it freezes. So it freezes after running all the initializations, so it's not the initlializations which are causing the slow response but the call to `big_class.blah`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that closely enough. OK, here's what's happening. `@my_arr << BigClass.new(depth+1)` is adding an instance (say `#<BigClass:0x00005cce59962970 @my_arr=[]>]>`) to the array held by the instance variable `@my_arr` for a *different instance*. `@my_arr = []` initialize that instance variable for `#<BigClass:0x00005cce59962970 @my_arr=[]>]>` but does not affect `@my_arr` for the different instance.

Comment: Right, that is the intention, but why is that causing the delay I am experiencing? My issue here is that running the below script will cause a long delay between the call to `big_class.blah` and an error message being printed. I am expecting that to be very fast, since it shouldn't have to interact with the ~10 million other objects I have just created

Comment: I forgot to mention that my computer (8GB) hung before reaching `puts "Reaches here"`. I don't know why you got that far unless it has to do with memory limitations (I have 8gb), but I can't imagine why `big_class.blah` would not raise an exception. Try `big_class.blah_blah_blah`.

Comment: I just tried `BigClass.new(1)` and it ran as expected.

Comment: Yeah same issue with `blah_blah_blah` (or anything else). It's not that it doesn't raise an exception, it's just that it takes a long time, even longer than it takes to run the initializers. That's okay thanks for your help anyway. Hopefully, someone will have an idea because I'm quite confused about the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I worked it out.

If I override the `#inspect` method of `BigClass` it no longer causes an issue. This makes me think that something internally is calling `#inspect` when handling the error. Since the default inspect will include the instance variables, and call inspect on them as well, if there are many instance variables and they all have many instance variables, then it could take a very long time to process.

The below code shows a version which runs as I would expect:

```
class BigClass
  # Increase this depending on your computer performance
  MAX_DEPTH = 8

  def initialize(depth = 0)
    @my_arr = []

    5.times do |i|
      unless depth > MAX_DEPTH
        @my_arr << BigClass.new(depth+1)
      end
    end
  end

  def inspect
    "now it works"
  end
end

big_class = BigClass.new

puts "Reaches here"

# Correctly raises an error now
big_class.blah_blah_blah

puts "Doesn't reach here"
```